# How do I run javascript inside of an html string using webview?

Tags: javascript, android

How do I run a JavaScript code into `webview`?

Is it possible to use an existing URL and put the JavaScript into that URL from `webview` (not onPageFinished)  but I am unsure on how to do that, so I am trying to make a short html that will run the JavaScript.

```java
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");

String page = "<html>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<script>" +
                "document.write(javascript:Android.getdate())" +
                "</script>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>");
webView.loadUrl(page)
```

I expect that when `loadUrl` is run with that html string it will run the `getdate()` function and display the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable JavaScript for the WebView in it's WebSettings first.

```
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        if (webSettings != null) {
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }
```

Also if you want to load HTML instead of a URL, you need to use `loadData()`instead of `loadUrl()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        if (webSettings != null) {
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }

        //Enable setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to use Chrome DevTools in debug build
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {            
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");

        String page = "<html>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<h1>Test</h1>" +
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                "   document.write(Android.getDate());" +
                "</script>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";

        webView.loadData(page, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getDate() {
        return "<p>The current date is " + new Date().toString() + "</p>";
    }
}
```